# How can I tell if a node I am using is a full archive node?

Tags: nodes, web3-providers, ethers.js, eth-call, archive-node

What is the best way to tell if the node I am is using a full archive node?

One way I know if is to `call` a contract from the context of an old block, but this requires an RPC call and is not explicit (the `call` may fail for other reasons). Additionally, different clients (geth, party, etc.) return error messages, so this is not reliable. Is there a way to do this explicitly?

Comment: I believe that you are explaining why you don't want to use `contract.methods.func(arg1, arg2).call(null, blockNumber)`, but I did not quite understand your explanation.

Comment: You can just catch the error, and `if (!error.message.startsWith("Invalid JSON RPC response"))`, then you know that you are not using a full archive node.

Comment: Of course, make sure to call a function which cannot revert (preferably a `pure` function).

Comment: i.e., a function with no `assert`, `require`, `revert`, array access operations, division, modulo, external calls (to another contract), and probably a few more of those. For example a getter function of any one of your (non-array) public variables.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using `.call()`? That error message you  mentioned can be different depending on the underlying client (geth, parity, etc.), so that is not reliable.

Comment: I can think of `web3.eth.getPastLogs` and `contract.getPastEvents` (which internally just calls the former AFAIK). If non-fully archived nodes support these two, then perhaps `web3.eth.getBalance`, though you'll need to call it with a past block number, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A full archive node has access to the historical state of the blockchain.
For example, if the node returns balance of an account (which has some eth) at block 1 then that node will be an archive node.

1. Case of an archive node:

```
$ curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xe5Fb31A5CaEE6a96de393bdBF89FBe65fe125Bb3", "0x1"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localh
ost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x3635c9adc5dea00000","id":1}
```

In the above code snippet, we are querying balance of [0xe5Fb31A5CaEE6a96de393bdBF89FBe65fe125Bb3](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe5Fb31A5CaEE6a96de393bdBF89FBe65fe125Bb3) an address which received 1k ETH during the genesis block.

**Asserting the result of the above JSON-RPC call to be equal to 1K ETH will explicitly indicate if the node is an archive node.**

2. Case of a non archive node:

```
$ curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xe5Fb31A5CaEE6a96de393bdBF89FBe65fe125Bb3", "0x1"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://cloudflare-eth.com/
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"missing trie node d67e4d450343046425ae4271474353857ab860dbc0a1dde64b41b5cd3a532bf3 (path )"}}
```

A non archive node will not be able to return the balance at block 1 for the above  address.

Comment: Thank  you. One folllow-up question: do you know of a way to do this without making an RPC call?

Comment: you can also use the javascript console provided by nodes https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console and make the same getBalance request as above.